# Conditional testing modules on page, if they exists - using Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

New user of Cypress here - and a new 'tester' as well; so be gentle, please. :-)

I'm making a website, where a user can insert a mix of 10 different modules on a bunch of different pages.

I'm trying to make some tests, then (ideally) goes through all the different modules on a given page. And foreach module then it would run a set of tests for the given module.

## Example:

For simplicity's sake, let's say that there are 3 modules: `A`, `B` and `C`.

The user/customer puts together a page with this layout:

```
-----
| B |
| A |
| C |
| B |
| B |
| A |
| A |
| A |
-----
```

Ideally I would write a (set of) test(s), that would do something like:

```
it( 'tests all modules on a page', function() {
  cy.get( '.page-section' )
    .each( ( $el ) => {
      switch( $el.pageSection ){
        case 'A':
          testForA();
          break;
        case 'B':
          testForB();
          break;
        case 'C':
          testForC();
          break;    
  }
}
```

I can read on this page here: [Conditional Testing with Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#Element-existence) , that conditional testing with Cypress should be done on very specific cases.

But this will be one big-ass test. Obviously it will be split up into several functions. But is this something that people do with Cypress? Or am I treating this hammer like a screwdriver? ... I can't find any tutorials/guides on to set something like this up (with the different cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This largely depends on the purpose of this particular test. I'll explore two different scenarios that have different pros and cons.

1. This test is something that you have agreed upon with business team.

This means unless it passes as described (10 modules on the page of 3 different types), the feature (page with modules) is not complete. In this case you actually can do exactly what you do already - your test looks at the modules, their order and functionality as a whole. It is possible to split the test functions, as you have already suggested and simplifying the switch statement, for instance, by putting test functions in a map and just calling functions from that map, where the key is module name/id; but this is a minor decision. The main thing that you, as a test designer, have decided that either *the whole thing* works or it doesn't.

There are downsides to such an approach, namely the test may become brittle and not work 100% of the time, if there are too many condition checks and DOM queries (at least, this has been my experience with cypress and other e2e testing platforms). The other downside is that when test fails, there is no immediate feedback on why exactly that happens.

2. This is a test for developers to get feedback about state of the feature faster and keep track of feature regression.

The focus of such tests shifts to parts of the feature. Ideally, the developer writes tests for all the smaller parts and if those work, the whole page works. For instance, the developer writes different tests are *independent* and

- verify that container can host multiple modules
- verify the order of those modules
- verify that modules of the same type can be placed on one page
- verify rendering of the module *without* this container
- verify interaction between two given components, if there's supposed to be some

et c., et c.

These tests have better stability and the developer gets more information, but at the cost of developing and maintaining all this test code. The developer may be certain that if tests A, B & C work, then the whole page surely must work as well. But they've never actually tested it, so they don't know for sure.

If you want to have these benefits (and want to deal with the downsides) - then you'll need to create more independent tests in your suite.

---

This answer got a bit long, but the thing with testing strategies I've noticed that there's no clear-cut winner. So it is mostly up to you to see what parts of your application are more important for you and whether or not you are capable of maintaining tests later.